# Remove "trace" field from ResponseStatusException

Tags: spring-boot

In my spring  controller I return a `ResponseStatusException` if no entity is found, like this:

```
@GetMapping("/categories/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Category> getCategoryById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
    try {
      return new ResponseEntity<Category>(categoryService.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (CategoryNotFoundException ex) {
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

I would expect the answer to be something like:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-22T12:25:29.913+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "could not find category with ID: XYZ'.",
    "path": "/categories/XYZ"
}
```

But the response also includes a long field `"trace"` with the nested exception.
Is there a way to get rid of the trace field?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Seems the field "trace" is present if you have "spring-boot-devtools" in your dependencies.
I do not see such traces in my outputs after excluding devtools.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, the "trace" field is gone without the devtools, thank!

Comment: It could only be configured in application.properties with "server.error.include-stacktrace=never" as mentioned in @KimchiMan answer.

Comment: @aschmid I work adding the property "server.error.include-stacktrace=never" Thank you!

Comment: ```ALWAYS: Always add stacktrace information.
NEVER: Never add stacktrace information.
ON_PARAM: Add stacktrace attribute when the appropriate request parameter is not "false".
```
ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorProperties.IncludeStacktrace.html

Answer (score 109):

Open `application.properties` and add the below line:

```
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
```

Answer (score 34):

`spring-boot-devtools` sets the property `server.error.include-stacktrace` to **always**.

You can keep devtools, yet remove the trace, with the following in your `application.yml`:

```
server:
  error:
    include-stacktrace: on_trace_param
```

Answer (score 10):

I know I am late to party, but I recently came across the scenario and resolved with another solution, as none of the above solutions worked in my case.

I an using `Spring-boot-devtools`, and it automatically sets **`server.error.include-stacktrace=always`**

So, I suppressed the stack trace by overriding `fillInStackTrace` method in your exception class as below.

```
public class DuplicateFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    @Override
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

ps1: I referred [this](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/if_you_use_exceptions_for_path_control_dont_fill_in_the_stac) article.

**ps2: you can also try following suggested solutions in other answers:**

**(None of these worked in my case)**

if you're using `application.properties` file, add following line to your properties file.

```
server.error.include-stacktrace=on_trace_param
```

if you're using `application.yml` file, add following line to your yml file.

```
server:
  error:
    include-stacktrace: on_trace_param
```

Comment: Love your solution, because you can have a specific Class that extends RuntimeExcepiton, and only take out the stacktrace from exceptions that use this class and not from other, which can keep it.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for server.error.include-stacktrace=ON_PARAM

when I tried on_trace_param Eclipse indicated the value was not valid

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).